# Llamar a funcion js desde un fichero en la carpeta de Scripts en proyecto MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mvc

Estoy intentando llamar a funciones JavaScript en un proyecto MVC. Según he leido, he de configurar el fichero "BundleConfig.cs" en la carpeta "App_Start". Esta carpeta la he creado yo manualmente junto con el archivo BundleConfig. Tambien he creado manualmente dos archivos. Uno "Web.config" en el root del proyecto y otro "web.config" en la carpeta de "Views". Pongo el código referente a los archivos:

Archivo *BundleConfig.cs*

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace seguridaddeTelefonia_JAVASCRIPT.App_Start
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/functions").Include(
            "~/Scripts/Lineas.js"));
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/functions").Include(
            "~/Scripts/Terminales.js"));
        }
    }
}
```

Archivo *Web.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="seguridaddeTelefonia_JAVASCRIPT" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

Archivo *web.config* en la carpeta de *Views*

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Finalmente, mi llamada a los scripts en la vista que me interesa:

```
 ...
    </form>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    @using System.Web.Optimization
    @Scripts.Render("~Scripts/Lineas.js")
  </body>
</html>
```

Al compilar, el tag `@Scripts.Render("~Scripts/Lineas.js")` se sobreesribe en rojo dando el siguiente error:

```
Error   CS7069  La referencia al tipo 'IHtmlString' confirma que está definida en 'System.Web', pero no se encontró
```

Imagen con la esctructura de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La razón por la cual he creado manualmente estos ficheros y la carpeta App_Start es porque no me las crea VS. El proyecto ha sido generado mediante aspnet-codegenerator en powerShell. Lo cierto es que no veo donde puede estar el fallo para que MVC ejecute las funciones que hay en los scripts. Todo el código es autogenerado mediante scripts. ¿Alguien puede indicarme que mas puedo hacer?, lo he probado todo ya y no hay forma...

Un saludo, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Quieres agregar un archivo js a tu pagina?

Comment: ¿Usas asp.net o asp.net core?

Comment: asp.net core. Toma, te paso los scripts de power shell que he utilizado para montar el servicio. Como no veo como pasártelo, los cuelgo en la misma pregunta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Es que asp.net core sustituyo web.config con appsettings.json y lo puedes ver en tu directorio

Comment: Si, eso he leido. Entonces, como debo configurar mi fichero appsettings.json?

Comment: mira esto: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Muchas gracias. Le hecho un vistazo.

Comment: Perfecto. Ya veo. Mediante la carpeta wwwroot, ya veo que hay una subcarpeta js. Entiendo que ahí deberé de incluir mis ficheros js y después, de alguna manera, referenciarlos en mi proyecto. No?

Comment: Sip, eso para agregar los archivos

Answer (score 0):

Veo varios problemas por ejemplo la presencia de los web.config pero me centrare en la pregunta.

Primero en tu *BundleConfig* podemos modificar un poco:

```
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Optimization;
namespace seguridaddeTelefonia_JAVASCRIPT.App_Start 
{ 
  public class BundleConfig 
  { 
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) 
    { 
      bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/functions")
      .Include( 
        "~/Scripts/Lineas.js",
        "~/Scripts/Terminales.js"
        )); 
     } 
  } 
}
```

De esta manera agregamos los dos archivos bajo un mismo nombre.

Entonces en tu vista debes hacer la referencia al nombre del bundles que agregaste **no** a tu nombre de archivo.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/functions")
```

Ya que ese es el nombre que hemos especificado en tu *BundleConfig*

Comment: Finalmente lo resolví. No era necesaria tanta parafernalia como pensaba jeje. Muchas gracias por vuesta ayuda!

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta puedes marcarla como correcta o puedes agregar una tu mismo de como lo solucionaste. Asi posible futuros visitantes se beneficiaran